# Iterate json, look in text file and append data if not exists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this ever changing json file with users/viewers of a live stream who join and leave. I want to append all users who is currently viewing and the new users who join the live stream to a text file. So the script has to run and append new viewers until the live stream ends and the viewer list becomes empty.

My script doesn't behave as expected, so I am doing something horrible wrong why I need your help. :)

First my while loop doesn't work as intended. It doesn't stop when the list is empty.

Second it just keeps running in an infinite loop keeping appending everything over and over again. So the test if it is already in the text file does not work.

I hope you can help me solve this. I am still pretty much a newbie learning, so treat me like a child who needs it well explained :D In advance, thank you for your assistance.

Expected behavior:

- Look if stream is active (while any viewers are present) else if empty, break
- Iterate the json file.
- Open a text file.
- Test if the userid's from json are already present in the text file.
- If not already present append userid and nickname.
- If already present skip them since they are already in the text file.

```
while data['result']['list'] != '':             # keep it running while list is not empty.
    with open('test.txt', 'a+') as viewers:     # open text file.
        for users in data['result']['list']:    # iterate json.
            for line in viewers:                # iterate text file
                if users['userId'] in line:     # look if userId is already in textfile.
                    break                       # all users has already been added to text file. No new users to add.

                else:                           # append users to file.                   
                    viewers.write(users['nickName'] + '\n')
                    viewers.write(str(users['userId']) + '\n')
```

The json output looks like this and is changing whenever a viewer join or leave the live stream:

```
{
  "code": 1,
  "result": {
    "liveType": 0,
    "watchNum": 140,
    "rank": 0,
    "duringF": 0,
    "list": [
      {
        "userId": 294782,
        "nickName": "user1"
      },
      {
        "userId": 200829,
        "nickName": "user2"
     }
    ],
    "earning": 4183,
    "likeNum": 233
  },
  "msg": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Your loop never changes `data['result']['list']`, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, since `data['result']['list']` is a list, the way to tell if it's not empty is `while len(data['result']['list']) > 0`

Comment: the `while` is also redundant, you don't need it if you have the interior `for` reading the list.

Comment: It's probably better to keep a dictionary/list of some sort for your `viewers` and then periodically dump the data a text file.  This way you can keep track of who has already been read and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this code.

1. You're testing for an empty list incorrectly. A list is not a string.
2. You're not rereading the JSON file, so `data` never changes.
3. When you open a file in append mode, you're positioned at the end of the file, so trying to read the file won't read anything. You need to seek to the beginning of the file first.
4. You're writing the new user to the file for every line that doesn't match. You should wait until the end of the loop, and only write if the user was never found.
5. `users['userId'] in line` will match when the userID is a substring of the line. So if the userID is `10`, it will match if `101` or `110` are in the line. You need to do an exact match of the line.

```
users = set(open("test.txt").read().splitlines()[1::2]) # set of userIds from file
with open("test.txt", "a") as viewers:
    while True:
        with open("json_file.json") as j:
            data = json.load(j)
        for user in data['result']['list']:
            if user['userId'] not in users:
                users.add(user['userId'])
                viewers.write(user['nickName'] + '\n')
                viewers.write(str(user['userId']) + '\n')
```

An improvement to this would be to check whether the JSON file's modification time has changed since the previous iteration, and skip the rest of the loop if it hasn't.

Comment: I get:     viewers.write(users['nickName'] + '\n')
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Sorry, I copied your code and forgot that I renamed the variable.

Comment: Why did you use a plural word for the variable that holds just a single user?

Comment: It kinda work now. But it doesn't add new nicknames and userid's to the text file automatically as the json updates. I call an api btw... also if I rerun the script it will still make duplicates. So it seems like the "if user['userId'] not in users:" doesn't work as expected :) Also, can you explain what ".splitlines()[1::2])" does so I don't use code that I don't understand. I very much like to learn by this.

Comment: `splitlines()` splits the file into a list of lines. `[1::2]` is a slice that gets every odd line, those are the ones with the userids.

Comment: if I add a viewers.write(str(user['price'] + '\n') after the viewers.write(str(user['userId']) + '\n') then what should the slice be? [1::3] ?? in order to get the id number

Comment: Yes. The third number in the slice is the stride.